# How to show that $ 0 \to E_{0,n}^2 \to H_n \to E_{1,n-1}^2 \to 0 $ is exact?

Tags: homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

> Suppose that a spectral sequence converging to $ H_\ast$ has $ E_{pq}^r = 0$ for all $ p\neq 0,1 $. Show that there are exact sequences 
>   $$ 
> 0 \to E_{0,n}^2 \to H_n \to E_{1,n-1}^2 \to 0 \,.
> $$
>   Furthermore, generalize this claim for a spectral sequence with two non-zero columns at $ p=k,l \geq 0 $.

I've solved the first part of the exercise, but I don't see how to generalize this to nonadjacent columns $k$ and $l$.

Comment: It's exactly the same reasonning except that you have to look at a higher page for the spectral sequence to degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, without loss of generality, that $k = 0$ and $l > 0$.

The convergence $E_{p, q}^n \Rightarrow H_{p + q}$ guarantees a filtration of $H_n$ for each $n$,
$$
0 = F_{-1} H_n \subseteq F_0 H_n \subseteq \cdots \subseteq F_{n - 1}H_n \subseteq F_n H_n = H_n
$$
such that $E_{p, q}^\infty \cong F_p H_{p + q} / F_{p - 1} H_{p + q}$.
The condition $E_{p, q}^2 = 0$ for $p \neq 0, l$ tells us that 
$$
0 = F_{-1} H_n \subseteq F_0 H_n = \cdots = F_{l - 1} H_n \subseteq F_l H_n = \cdots = F_n H_n = H_n.
$$

Observe that $E_{0, n}^{l + 1} = E_{0, n}^\infty \cong F_0 H_n / F_{-1} H_n = F_0 H_n$ since $F_{-1} H_n = 0$.

Now since $E_{l, n - l}^{l + 1} = E_{l, n - l}^\infty \cong F_l H_n / F_{l - 1} H_n$ there is a short exact sequence 
$$
0 \to F_0 H_n \to F_l H_n \to E_{l, n - l}^\infty \to 0,
$$
which after plugging in the isomorphisms we've established, corresponds to,
$$
0 \to E_{0, n}^{l + 1} \to H_n \to E_{l, n - l}^{l + 1} \to 0,
$$
as desired.